# Flyway: how to find out maximum version available to migrate()?

Tags: flyway

I'd like to detect the condition where the user's database is newer than the maximum version available to migration (for example, the user downgraded to an older version of the software). When I run the following:

```
System.out.println("source: " + flyway.status().getVersion().toString());
System.out.println("target: " + flyway.getTarget().toString());
```

I get the following output:

```
source: 8
target: 9223372036854775807
```

How do I get the actual maximum version available to `migrate()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no functionality to query the available migrations. Feel free to raise an issue :-)

**Update:** You can now use `Flyway.info()` for this and more.

Comment: Was this feature ever added?